# numpy, altering shape of an array using assignment statement to shape attribute behaves differnetly than when reshape is used

Tags: numpy

I have been puzzled with different behavior of following two ways to change shape of numpy arrays:

```
x.shape = (3,4)    
x = x.reshape(3,4)
```

Here is an example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
##### Case 1
In [2]: fa = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
In [3]: x = fa
In [4]: x is fa
Out[4]: True
In [5]: x.shape = (3,4)         # RESHAPING does not affect x 
In [6]: x is fa
Out[6]: True
########Case 2 ########
In [7]: fa = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
In [8]: x = fa
In [11]: x.reshape(3,4) is fa   # RESHAPING makes x a shallow copy
Out[11]: False
########Verify x is shallow copy
In [13]: fa = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
In [14]: x.reshape(3,4).base is fa.base
Out[14]: True
```

I am unable to understand the reasons as to why in the first case of reshaping, x remains same as fa but in the second case after reshaping  x becomes a shallow copy of fa.

Comment: It is not a "deep copy": try `fa.reshape(3, 4).base is fa.base`.

Comment: Thanks. I agree. I have amended the question accordingly.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html#numpy.ndarray.shape. `In[5]` is an in-place operation, modifying the shape of `x` (and `fa`).  The `reshape` method (and `np.reshape` function) returns a new array.  It will be a `view` (in most cases).  The docs should be clear about that.  Or does you question go deeper than that?

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. This answers my question. One is in place change and the other returns a new array which is a view.